# Can an aggregate root hold references of members of another aggregate root?

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I know that outside of aggregates I can't change anything inside an aggregate without passing by his root. That said I would like to know if an aggregate root can hold references of members (objects insides) of another aggregate root? (following DDD rules)

Example :

a **Calendar** contain a list of **phases** which contain a list of **sequences** which contain a list of **assignations**

Calendar is root because phases and sequences and assignations only work in context of a calendar.

You also have **Students** and **Groups** of student (called groups)

It is possible (following DDD rules) to make Groups holding references of **assignations**  or it need to pass by the root for accessing groups from assignations ?

Thanks.

Comment: This feels to me like it belongs on SO.

Comment: Well i dont think. This is a programming question. Stackoverflow is more like a technical questions i think ?

Comment: Is it possible for a Group to change Assignation, making Calendar invalid? I would say that a Group should only hold the ID of the Assignation, and not the reference to the object Assignation. This way only Calendar is responsible for changing Assignations, and connecting Groups and Assignations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the [basics of UML class diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)?

> Would like to know if its possible to
>   hold multiple references of an
>   aggregate root (groups) inside another
>   aggregate root (calendar) member ?

Classes can be **associated** with any other classes, in any way they want. That's the whole purpose of designing a system.

> Also how a list of references are
>   represented in UML ? it is a simple
>   relation ?

A list of references can either be **aggregation** (has a) or **composition** (owns a).

> But assignations must hold multiple references to groups of students. (Must work two sides)

This isn't really clear, you are talking about a bidirectional relation between groups and students? In any case, perhaps [this article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/) on many to many relations can provide you with some insight.

If there was no such thing as “student”, would there be meaning to “student group” ? Probably not.
If there was no such thing as “student group”, would there be meaning to “student” ? Probably.

UPDATE:

> It is possible (fellowing DDD rules)
>   to make Groups holding references of
>   assignations or it need to pass by the
>   root for accessing groups from
>   assignations ?

I never modelled a system with DDD in mind, but by reading the previously mentioned article. I would say, **try to prevent it when not necessary**, [if there are no performance issues](http://stochastyk.blogspot.com/2008/06/associations-in-domain-driven-design.html), access the groups through assignations. That is, if that's the correctly chosen aggregate root.

Apply the "student, student group" example to all your elements to choose the correct aggregate roots.

Comment: But in a DDD i must avoid bidirectional stuff. Is there a way to transfoem this to become unidirectional?

Comment: @Rushino: Could you update your question to clarify the bidirectional relation more clearly?

Comment: I edited my question. Should be more clear now. I am sorry for unclear parts. Actually all i need to know if its an aggregate root can hold references to another aggregate roots objects part of the aggregate.

Comment: @Rushino: Updated the reply to answer your better formulated question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the significance of an assignation? If there is a natural relationship between Groups and assignations then the group can hold a direct reference to it's Assignations. But as you noted, changes to assignations can only be made through the Calendar if that is the root.

I think we need more detail about the relationship of Calendars, Phases, Assignations, and Groups. What is an Assignation, how is it used?

Comment: Assignations are like taking a group and a period (start date and end date) and bind them together in a sequence which is owned by a phase which is owned by a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some wild assumptions about your data structure and say

## Yes

otherwise there's no way of establishing and maintaining the reference. The different aggregate roots would still have their own repository.

hey, if I'm wrong, someone (Pierre, probably) will correct me with a link and then we'll both learn something.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding:

An outside entity can ask a root for a copy of an entity inside that aggregate for its own use.  However, the root should not return a reference to the actual entity. Only the root is allowed to change properties in the aggregate so that it can maintain a valid state.

It can be difficult to enforce these rules in code (it is easy to provide a reference to a collection and add/remove directly from it instead of asking the root AddItem/RemoveItem).